# Bootstrap-Table Custom Search

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-table

I have a custom search that looks like this, but how can I use it
in all columns and not just colName column?

https://live.bootstrap-table.com/code/janttila/5112

```
function customSearch(data, text) {
    return data.filter(function (row) {

        return  row.colName.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, "").indexOf(text.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, "")) > -1

    })
  }
```

Comment: Use [`search()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/search())

Answer (score 2):

you could iterate through all the columns. But maybe provide some more code to get an valid solution. I don't know how your data object exactly looks like.

//EDIT:
regarding your data structure, the function will look like this:

```
    function customSearch(data, text) {
return data.filter(function (row) {
 
  for (let items of Object.values(row)){
    if (items.toString().toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, "").indexOf(text.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, "")) > -1){
    return true
  }
  }
})
}
```

we iterate thrugh all the evalues in row and check if any of that suits the search text. But be aware, your dataset has the entry amount as well which you are not displaying. This one will be also included for the search

//EDIT2:

```
function customSearch(data, text) {
return data.filter(function (row) {
 searchFor = ["id", "name", "price"]
  
 for (elem of Object.keys(row)){
   if (searchFor.indexOf(elem) < 0) {
     delete row[elem]
   }
 }

  for (let items of Object.values(row)){
    if (items.toString().toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, "").indexOf(text.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, "")) > -1){
    return true
  }
  }
})
}
```

Comment: https://live.bootstrap-table.com/code/janttila/5112

Comment: Yes it kind of works but stuckes on those object keys that are not strings, i need to search only the row.columnName in the object. and specify witch culumns i want to search. row.colOne, row.colTwo and so on.

Comment: alright, i added a function which deletes the key-value-pairs from the object if they are not in a list you can specify

Comment: Great!only one problem i cant solve. If i Remove Column price it dosnt show its data enymore. I want ut to show but not be included in the search